# How to establish communication between devices on separate local networks?

Tags: networking, iot

There is a number of devices with Internet access but they are on LANs and have no public IPs. As time goes by more devices will be added.

I need to be able to communicate with each device on demand (metrics, diagnostics, updates, ...). I do not need or want full root access.

I understand I could create an SSH tunnel if I had a public IP host on the other end. However, I am concerned that such a public host is too big of an attack vector.

I thought that using a public IP computer as a merely rendezvous point could be viable.

The scheme could work like this:

```
dev1 - device I need to access, no public IP, has dev2's public key
dev2 - my computer, no public IP, has dev1's public key
proxy - computer with public IP

LAN x      |  Internet   |  LAN y
           |             | 
+------+   |  +-------+  |  +------+
| dev1 |   |  | proxy |  |  | dev2 |
+------+   |  +-------+  |  +------+
           |             |

1) `dev1` registers itself with the proxy as `online`
2) `dev1` periodically checks with the proxy if there are any pending connections
3) `dev2` checks with proxy that `dev1` is online and signals a need to communicate.
4) Once `dev1` checks again, it sees a connection attempt and mutual authentication starts.
5) Authentication, key negotiation, ...
6) Communication
```

It has several drawbacks

1. Feels like I'm reinventing the wheel.
2. `dev1` needs to poll the proxy. So I either need to poll aggressively or establishing connection can take a long time.
3. I would need to introduce some custom message passing at the proxy.
4. Do all the authentication manually on top of that message passing scheme.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by “not having a public IP”. It sounds like you mean listening on a port on a public IP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your broker model could work but trying to establish a connection through the broker makes no sense. A couple of "mail boxes" would suffice.

Say dev1 wants to tell dev2 something. It sends a message to proxy which creates a queue for dev2 and adds the message to it. It responds with any message for dev1 from its queue if it already exists or with "No mail for you".

Each dev could just send messages as it needs to and periodically check mail. Proxy does not need to know anything about devs, it just manages message queues.

Authentication of devs with the proxy is a separate issue independent of the routing logic.